# Is there any way to play the google drive video automatically in iframe?

Tags: google-drive-api, autoplay

I am trying to play the google drive video in iframe but wants to play it automatically. youtube video links are playing automatically but for drive video I have to click twice on iframe. can I able to set autoplay for the drive video as well. I am attaching the link of stackblitz project. please check and let me know if there is any solution. Thanks.

Stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/drive-video-autoplay-issue?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.